# Vim on Mac (iTerm) enters insert mode with every keystroke

Tags: vim

Any keystroke (except for Esc) puts vim into insert mode and inserts the character. Example: I sit in Normal mode, press `k` to go up, vim goes into insert mode and types `k` under the cursor. Same for `:` and other keys. `Esc` or `Ctrl-[` returns to Normal mode, but the behavior persists.

This doesn't happen on entering vim, but on occasion (quite often) it gets into this mode and stays until I kill the terminal window. It's not global (so if I have another vim instance in another terminal, the state does not propagate) so it's probably not about the input modes / keyboard layouts.

Running a Mac M1 with macOS 12.

What could it be?

**Update**:

1. It happens after I hit Delete key in Insert mode (consistently).
2. I have a binding that exits Insert mode on a key sequence (`inoremap saj <esc>l`), and typing that exits Insert mode for good after it gets stuck. However, exiting through `Esc` or `Ctrl-[` doesn't work as mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in Normal mode? Your experience would be the same if you were in Insert mode all the time.

Comment: It would, but it's not saying --INSERT-- at the bottom after I exit it with Esc. I agree that the experience fits pretty well, but vim claims otherwise.

Comment: Does this happen with `$ vim --clean`?

Comment: No actually, it doesn't. Interesting